# infinite loop issue for advice in Python 2.7

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Here is my code to find k-th smallest element in an unsorted array, code will enter into infinite loop. I understand why there is infinite loop (see my comments), but my ideas to fix them are a bit hacking, wondering if any elegant solution?

BTW, I do not want to sort. I want to find elegant solution without sorting and able to handle the case when all elements are equal.

Using Python 2.7.

```
def find_kth(numbers, start, end, k):
    if end == start:
        if k == 1:
            return numbers[start]
        else:
            raise Exception('invalid input!')

    mid_index = start + (end - start) / 2
    mid_value = numbers[mid_index]
    origin_start = start
    origin_end = end

    while start <= end:
        while start <= end and numbers[start]<=mid_value:
            start += 1
        while start <= end and numbers[end] > mid_value:
            end -= 1
        if start < end:
            numbers[start], numbers[end] = numbers[end], numbers[start]
        else:
            if start-origin_start == k:
                return mid_value
            elif start-origin_start > k:
                return find_kth(numbers, origin_start, start-1, k) # infinite loop here
            else:
                return find_kth(numbers, start, origin_end, k-(start-origin_start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [5,5,5,5]
    find_kth(numbers, 0, len(numbers)-1, 2) # find the 2nd smallest element, I count element from one, other than from zero
```

Comment: How about `sorted(numbers)[1]`?

Comment: @KlausD., thanks I want to find non-sorting solutions.

Comment: Then, please define the requirements for your function properly.

Comment: Sure, updated the post for my requirement without sorting and handle equal elements. @KlausD., thanks for the heads-up to make the question more clear.

Comment: "I don't want to..." is not really a requirement and the beginning of many bad solutions. So, why don't you want to sort and use less efficient looping instead. What makes you think sorting does work if all elements are equal? It is in fact the best case for sorting.

Comment: _Any_ correct solution to this problem essentially involves sorting. But you certainly _don't_ need to completely sort the list, you can perform a [partial sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting). However, Python's built-in sort aka TimSort runs at C speed, so in general it will run faster than any partial sort you write that performs its loops at Python speed.

Comment: I assume you are coding this yourself as a learning exercise. If that's not the case and you want an efficient solution from the standard library, please take a look at the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module.

Comment: @PM2Ring, thanks and your got my thought correctly. Wondering if any solution like partition by pivot or quick select which handle the case when all elements are equal -- without using heap and without using sorting?

Comment: @KlausD., sorry for any confusions, I mean sorting definitely works, but time complexity is O(n log n), wondering if any better ideas not sorting which has better time complexity, and could handle all equal case, similar to partition by pivot in quick sort or quick select?

Comment: Yes, you can do a partial quicksort, as discussed in the Wikipedia link I gave earlier; the time complexity of such an algorithm is O(n + k log k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a one-liner?!

```
>>> def find_kth(numbers, start, end, k):
...     return sorted(numbers[start:end])[k]
... 
>>> 
>>> find_kth([5,5,5,5], 0, 4, 2)
5
>>> find_kth([1,5,2,3], 0, 4, 2)
3
```

Comment: Thanks tdelaney, I want to find non-sorting solutions to handle when all elements are equal.

Comment: This works when all elements are equal... but if you don't want to sort, then you'll need something else.

Comment: Thanks and agree with you. Is there a way like partition around pivot value idea in quick sort, and able to handle equal case?

Comment: I don't understand... this technique does handle the equal case as shown in the python shell session I posted. Are you saying you want to avoid the cost of sorting when elements are equal? My guess is that by the time you figure out which numbers are equal, the sort is faster. What about `[5,0,5,1,5,3]` for example. Figuring out what's equal is less expensive with a sort.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct, I mean "Are you saying you want to avoid the cost of sorting when elements are equal". Is there a way to use partition by pivot idea, and handle all equal case?

Comment: Thanks for all the help tdelaney, mark your reply as answer.